# Stored Procedure not returning value with Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

Aim: to check if a user has permission to view a page and if they do not redirect them.

Issue: I get an error (see below) when I hit the `Command.ExecuteNonQuery()` line. To fix this I had added `Parameter.Size = 1` but then it 'passed' every time.

Error message:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: String[0]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

I have checked that both `EmployeeID` and `ApplicationID` have a value being passed in. I do not see to be able to get "Access" value (which is a single letter) out.

Stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSitePermission]
    @EmployeeID varchar(max)
    ,@AppID int
    ,@Access nvarchar OUTPUT
AS

BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT @Access= Access FROM [TbSitePermissions] 
WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID AND ApplicationID = @AppID AND LIVE = 1

END
```

Aspx.vb code:

```
If oUserFunctions.PrcAppPermissionChecker(CInt(oUser.EmployeeID), Me.sModuleNum) = "N" Then
           Response.Redirect("../../Default.aspx")
End If
```

Function:

```
Public Function PrcAppPermissionChecker(vEmployeeID As String, vApp As Integer) As String

        '   Try
        Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim command As New SqlCommand
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim sAvailable As String = "N"
        Dim ConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("GWPemcoConnectionString").ToString()

        connection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        connection.Open()

        command.Connection = connection
        command.CommandText = "spSitePermission"
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        command.Parameters.Clear()

        Dim parameter As SqlParameter = command.Parameters.Add("@Access", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        ' parameter.Size = 1

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeeID", vEmployeeID)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("AppID", vApp)

        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sAvailable = command.Parameters("@Access").Value.ToString
        command.Dispose()

        '   Catch ex As Exception
        '  End Try

        Return sAvailable

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx).

> *"Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored."* - MSDN -

**.Net**

```vb
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeeID", vEmployeeID)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("AppID", vApp)

sAvailable = CStr(command.ExecuteNonQuery()) '<-- Retrieves the [Access] column.
```

**SQL**

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSitePermission]
    @EmployeeID varchar(max),
    @AppID int
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 
        [Access] 
    FROM 
        [TbSitePermissions] 
    WHERE 
        [EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID AND 
        [ApplicationID] = @AppID AND 
        [LIVE] = 1
    ;
END;
```

Also, I suggest you use the `Using` keyword when working with `IDisposable` objects. Here's an example:

```vb
Public Function PrcAppPermissionChecker(vEmployeeID As String, vApp As Integer) As String
    Dim result As Object = Nothing
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("GWPemcoConnectionString").ToString())
        connection.Open()
        Using command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
            command.CommandText = "spSitePermission"
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeeID", vEmployeeID)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("AppID", vApp)
            result = command.ExecuteScalar()
        End Using
        connection.Close()
    End Using
    If (IsDBNull(result) OrElse (result Is Nothing)) Then
        Return CStr(Nothing)
    Else
        Return result.ToString()
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried adding  sAvailable = CStr(command.ExecuteNonQuery()) both before and after the command.ExecuteNonQuery but got the response of "-1". If I try the second piece of code connection and command come up as "hides in an enclosed block of code'

Comment: You may need to rename some of the variables. Did you see my edit regarding the SQL procedure part?

Comment: Did not see SQL change at the time then internet went down. Looks good now thank you.